# Outlook stopped receiving mail from one POP3 account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, pop3

UPDATE:
All my POP accounts are configured with an inbox in the same joint PST file. When I changed the problematic account to use its own PST file, mail was downloaded (all the messages from the server, not just the last few messages). Changing the account back - to use the joint PST file reintroduced the issue.

ORIGINAL POST:
I have my Outlook configured with 3 different POP emails, all on the same server (Rackspace's). I have this setup on two different computers - a laptop and a desktop.

All of a sudden, yesterday, the laptop stopped downloading emails from account A. It downloads emails from B and C (on the same email server), but not from A. The desktop can download emails from all accounts. Both laptop and desktop are connected to the same network.

I did install the F5 BIG IP client yesterday, uninstalling it made no real difference.

I deleted the account from Outlook and added it again - it made very little difference; emails are still not being downloaded. Outlook just says "Downloading messages" - there's no error or any other indication of a problem.

I'm stumped. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I deleted the account from Outlook and added it again

Delete the Outlook Profile, restart and make a new Outlook Profile.  Set up the Account and test.

Outlook Profiles can be found in Control Mail, Mail (Microsoft Outlook).

Since remaking the email account did not work, and since other email accounts work, it is likely an Outlook Profile error.

[image: Outlook Profile]

Comment: Will I then need to redfine all email acounts? I'd rather not do that if it's not the last resort. I have an update (updatted in the post), let's see if that provides some clues.

Comment: Yes, you would need to set up accounts again.  Since changing the single account did not do anything, then you need to redo the Outlook Profile. I have been using Outlook for a very long time and that is the correct approach. A person needs to redefine accounts when switching to a new computer, so this is a normal thing

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a new Outlook profile (Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and separately adding the problematic account (to use the joint PST file)？

If the problem disappears, it may be caused by the corrupted original Outlook profile. You just need to add the other two accounts in the new Outlook profile.